# Html Dropdown Menu Displays nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to diplay my table when I click a value in Dropdown list. When I view page code source, the table values are there but it's not showing. I would like to query from mysql using the value from dropdown and populate the table with datas from mysql query.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function jsFunction(value){   
    <?php
       $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dengue");
       // Check connection
       if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mapping_details where case_type='value'";
      echo '<div class="table-responsive ">          
      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Barangay</th>
    <th>Case Type</th>
    <th>Total Dengue Cases</th>      
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['brgy'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['case_type'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['total_case_brgy'] . "</td>";

   echo "</tr>";
  }
 echo '</tbody></table></div>';
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
}
 </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <select id ="ddl" name="ddl" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);">
      <option value='1'>One</option>
      <option value='2'>Two</option>
      <option value='3'>Three</option>
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Originally, in my other webpages, the php code is inside the body. But this time, I can't make it work if I use dropdown menu so that's why I put it inside the function for me to be able to use onchange function. I've read some answers using AJAX or JSON but I'm not familiar with those so if possible I only want to use javascript as maybe it is the simplest way.

Comment: Your php code is using echo inside a `script` tag... I would think that should be *not* inside a `script` tag and moved to the `body`.

Comment: Hi @Mottie. thanks for pointing out my mistake. Jon Foley's answer below creates error and queries nothing. Could you tell me how to execute this the right way ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know php well enough to help; but it sounds like the query code needs to be double checked.

Comment: @Mottie: I subject that the {$value} is not getting the right value that's why the query fetches nothing, any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is run PHP code in the browser, which you cannot do. All the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript is sent down to the client ( your browser ) and then is rendered and initialized by the browser. When you are calling your onchange event to call the jsFunction() you are trying to execute PHP within that function but- you are on the client-side running in chrome or firefox or some browser and you cannot execute PHP there. PHP has to run on page load and then can change the html, css, or JavaScript before it is sent down to the client.

There are two ways of doing what you want to do. You can send an Ajax request ( call your server using javascript ) to get new data or you can submit a form that reloads the page and you can run PHP like you are comfortable with- modifying the html, css, and/or javascript before it is returned to the client (browser).

Here is the non-ajax way which just keeps reloading the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <?php
        $value = isset( $_POST['ddl'] ) ? $_POST['dll'] : 1; // we are setting 1 as the default
       $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dengue");
       // Check connection
       if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mapping_details where case_type='{$value}'";
      $html= '<div class="table-responsive ">          
      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Barangay</th>
    <th>Case Type</th>
    <th>Total Dengue Cases</th>      
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $html.= "<tr>";
   $html.= "<td>" . $row['brgy'] . "</td>";
   $html.= "<td>" . $row['case_type'] . "</td>";
   $html.= "<td>" . $row['total_case_brgy'] . "</td>";

   $html.= "</tr>";
  }
 $html.= '</tbody></table></div>';
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
}
 </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="POST" action="">
        <select id="ddl" name="ddl">
          <option value='1'>One</option>
          <option value='2'>Two</option>
          <option value='3'>Three</option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <script>
        $("select#ddl").on("change",function(){
          $('form').submit();
        });
      </script>

      <?php echo $html; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I got this error: 'Notice: Undefined index: dll in C:\xampp\htdocs\Newfolder\testing.php on line 10'. Second thing is, it returns nothing, I can only see the table heads but no value in it, so maybe it queries nothing. Thanks.

Comment: I have fixed the issues. Now the code is tested code. Its runs fine.

Comment: Now the code makes more sense. Hope it will help you.

Comment: It will be visible once it is approved.

Comment: @KamalSingh: Hey, where's the fix you're talking about? I have approved thsi answer since this is he most helpful. I would be glad if you provide your own answer. Thanks!